# Sticky footer for bourbon neat

Tags: css, responsive-design, neat

Has anyone figured out how to create a footer which sticks at the bottom of the page while keeping it responsive using Bourbon Neat ?

All of the better known sticky footer solutions are not 'compatible' with Neat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the following technique for a few sites using Bourbon Neat:

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

though you do need to have a fixed height declared for the footer. But once that is done you can do the usual container etc. using Neat inside it.